# How to convert C style string to std::string with no copy in C++?

Tags: c++

As the question, I want to implement this kind of zero-copy,in the process of sending and receiving data in the network, C-style strings will often be used, but the upper layer want to use std::string,What should I do?

Comment: `std::string` manages its own memory.  There is no way for it to take ownership of your c-style string.  Can you use a `string_view` instead?

Comment: ... at the risk of, erm, tying yourself in knots with dangling pointers / references.